Horror movie about some ghost trying to abduct kids
So a couple of years back I remember watching a movie about a ghost or something (man without face) abducting kids, there were 2 places this happened at, during the same time-frame (i think). One part was Spanish speaking while the other was English. One scene that i remember was where this 'thing' was about to abduct the English speaking kid and it was raining and it was dark an i believe his mom defended him (the kid) 
I do believe this movie was released sometime during 2000-2010 not sure though.

It can be Intruders,

Two children living in different countries are visited nightly by a
  faceless being who wants to take possession of them.

It's a Spanish film and shows two timeline in two different country with having same faceless man becoming terror for a boy and a girl.
Full synopsis found at Twist Endings.
Even we have a puzzling plot twist explanation answer here but with lots of spoilers.
